# How to debug phantom power key presses after wake

Tags: suspend, power-management, lenovo

I have the strange problem, that in 50% of the cases when my laptop is resuming from suspention, the "Power Off" dialog keeps poping up until I reboot my system. Something I found with Journalctl is the following:

```
Okt 22 16:29:19 stefan-lenovo-x13 systemd-logind[1902]: Power key pressed short.
Okt 22 16:29:21 stefan-lenovo-x13 systemd-logind[1902]: Power key pressed short.
Okt 22 16:29:30 stefan-lenovo-x13 systemd-logind[1902]: Power key pressed short.
Okt 22 16:29:31 stefan-lenovo-x13 systemd-logind[1902]: Power key pressed short.
Okt 22 16:29:32 stefan-lenovo-x13 systemd-logind[1902]: Power key pressed short.
Okt 22 16:29:33 stefan-lenovo-x13 systemd-logind[1902]: Power key pressed short.
Okt 22 16:29:34 stefan-lenovo-x13 systemd-logind[1902]: Power key pressed short.
Okt 22 16:29:47 stefan-lenovo-x13 systemd-logind[1902]: Power key pressed short.
Okt 22 16:29:50 stefan-lenovo-x13 systemd-logind[1902]: Power key pressed short.
```

So logind is logging key presses to my power key without it being pressed. I don't think it's a hardware issue because it only happens after being in suspend mode.

The question is how can I debug this further? I suspect that it has something to do with not properly suspending my system, but how can I narrow that down?

Some details:

- Model: Lenovo ThinkPad X13 Gen 3 (AMD)
- OS: Ubuntu 23.04
- Kernel: Linux 6.4.3-060403-generic
- Firmware: R22ET65W (1.35 )

Comment: It is probably a driver issue. This is not an answer, but I suggest that you turn off the power key showing the Power Off menu from Settings/Power Management/Power button action.